# How to prevent Extension Bisect from disabling the extension with the feature I'm troubleshooting

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, bisection

A major VS Code extension (which comes installed with VS Code) isn't working for me. I've read bug reports for the behavior I'm seeing and the resolution isn't working for me either.

I want to use [Extension Bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to troubleshoot which other extension is inhibiting this one. However, it seems that Extension Bisect's first step is to disable all extensions and then ask me if the problem is still there. Yes, the problem is 'still' there because it disabled the extension with the feature I'm trying to troubleshoot.

**Q:** How can I tell Extension Bisect to *not* disable the specific extension with the feature I'm troubleshooting?

Answer (score 3):

It's counter-intuitive, but you [can actually](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/113568#issuecomment-759334161) keep an extension enabled during bisection by *disabling it before starting the bisect*, then manually re-enabling it after the bisect has calculated its todo-list.

1. Disable "MyExtension" manually (right-click in the "Extensions" sidebar, select "Disable");
2. Start an extension-bisect (⇧⌘P, `extension.bisect.start`);
3. Re-enable "MyExtension" manually before continuing with the bisect (right-click in the "Extensions" sidebar again, select "Enable".)

Comment: Does not work anymore as workaround

Comment: To be precise, you should mention in step 1 vscode or at least extension host must be reloaded.
As of end of 2023 this method still works